# Question about Newton derivative of $\max(0,x)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, non-smooth-optimization

From page 204 of [this book](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.00216.pdf): a function $f\colon X \to Y$ between Banach spaces is called Newton differentiable at $x$ if
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\lVert f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x+h)(h)\rVert}{\lVert h\rVert} =0$$
and $f'(x) \in \mathcal{L}(X,Y)$.

In page 213, Example 14.13, the author says that $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined $f(x) = \max(0,x)$ has Newton derivative
$$f'(x)(h) = \begin{cases}
0 &: x < 0\\
\delta h &: x = 0\\
h &: x >0
\end{cases}$$
where $\delta \in [0,1]$. Does something go wrong if we take $\delta$ outside of $[0,1]$? It looks like it doesn't matter what the derivative does at $x=0$ and the definition should hold.  Is there a good reason the author chooses $\delta$ in that interval?

Comment: The value of $\delta$ does not matter for Newton differentiability.